# Get Phone Brand in React Native app built using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building an app using Expo and React Native. I am in a situation where I need to get some device info such as: Phone Brand, Phone Model, and if possible Mac Address for both Android and iOS. Here I am only asking for Phone Brand. 
I have tried using Expo [Constants](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/) API, but it only returns the [Device Name](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/#constantsdevicename) (e.g. SM-A750GN for Samsung Galaxy A7). What I would like is to get the brand like 'Samsung'.

Is there any way to get the brand without ejecting from Expo? There is this library '[react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)' but I guess I would have to eject and link using react-native link.

Answer (score -1):

If Device name returns always same format starting with first 2 letter as an abbreviation for brand, you can write simple switch statement to get the brand.

I guess this is the best possible option for you.

```
let deviceName = 'SM-A750GN' 
let brand = deviceName.slice(0,2); // this will give you SM
let realBrand = ''

switch(brand) {
  case "SM":
    realBrand = "Samsung";
    break;
  case "AP":
    realBrand = "Apple";
    break;
  case "LG":
    realBrand = "LG";
    break;
  default:
    realBrand = "Undefined";
}
```

Comment: This is not true, deviceName property on Contants package returns the device name. It might be "JohnDoe", because users have the power to change device name in android.

Comment: @rafaelmorais If you check the source code 
public String getDeviceName() {
    return Build.MODEL;
} function return phone model and it can not be changed by users. you can find lost of all possible models in google web site. https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en